# how can i check if value is exist in redis-database using python-redis

Tags: python, redis

Here is my python code:

```
def check(request):
    import redis
    R = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)
    R.set("name","srk")
    r = R.HSET("name","srk")
    print(r)
```

It encounters an error with this error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /get_user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/soubhagya/.local/share/virtualenvs/pipenv-r-zifbiy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/soubhagya/.local/share/virtualenvs/pipenv-r-zifbiy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/soubhagya/.local/share/virtualenvs/pipenv-r-zifbiy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/soubhagya/Desktop/Dev/rango/backend/access/views.py", line 103, in get_user
    r = R.HSET("name","srk")
AttributeError: 'StrictRedis' object has no attribute 'HSET'
```

In py-redis, how can I check if a value exists or not in redis database.
A raw query will be helpful.
Please have a look into my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StrictRedis has no `HSET` function, but it does have the `hset` function for setting fields in Redis Hashes. That is the cause for the error you're getting.

To check whether a key exists in Redis with redis-py, use `r = R.exists("name")`.